# Changing registry values through bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file, character-encoding, registry

I'm trying to change some registry entries through a batch file.
All seems to work properly except these two:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sCountry /d "België" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v sCurrency /d "€" /f
```

These give me some odd values instead of the ones I want entered I get the values in the image provided here:

[Image](https://ibb.co/jgs1Zgv)

Any hints as to why/how to fix it?

Comment: works for me on my regional settings, what is your regional settings and what is the output of `echo €` from `cmd`

Comment: What is the output of the `chcp` command?

Comment: if your output from  `echo €` is the same as your results in the registry, try `chcp 437` and then do `echo €` again.

Comment: It is most likely the codepage `1252` will be the most compatible with your specific characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example based upon my comment, *(using codepage `1252`)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "RegKey=HKCU\Control Panel\International"

Rem This line will undefine any variable with a name beginning _cp
For /F Delims^= %%G In ('Set _cp 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%G="

Rem This line will save your current codepage to the variable %_cp%
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('"%__AppDir__%chcp.com"')Do For %%H In (%%G)Do Set "_cp=%%~nH"

Rem This line will change the codepage to 1252 if it is not already 1252
If Not %_cp% Equ 1252 (Set "_cpc=TRUE"
    "%__AppDir__%chcp.com" 1252 >NUL)

"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "%RegKey%" /V "sCountry" /D "België" /F >NUL
"%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Add "%RegKey%" /V "sCurrency" /D "€" /F >NUL

Rem This line will change the codepage back if it was not already 1252
If Defined _cpc "%__AppDir__%chcp.com" %_cp% >NUL
```